# How do you substitute on previous matches?

Tags: search, substitute

For example, if I have the following:

```
MY_VAR = "hello world"
print "the var %s" % MY_VAR
```

If I position the cursor on `MY_VAR` and press `*`, Vim highlights both matches. Suppose I want to rename this to `HELLO_WORLD_VAR`, how might I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you pressed `*`, your last search was for `MY_VAR`, i.e. equivalent to `/MY_VAR`. If you don't specify a search pattern in a substitution, the last search pattern is used, which is `MY_VAR` in your case. So you can simply use `:%s//HELLO_WORLD_VAR/g` to do the renaming.

Note that I used the `g` flag to indicate that all occurences should be replaced, not only the first on any line. It's not neccessary in your case, but probably makes sense in another context.

Comment: Related tip: I like to use `set gdefault` in my vimrc. This will add the `/g` flag by default, since this is what I want 95% of the time (you can "undo" the `/g` flag by adding it).

Comment: Great answer! I agree with @Carpetsmoker that `gdefault` is useful. Until you forget it's on and do `/g` :)