# Change Case of last searched pattern

Tags: replace, letter-case

I often use `#` key to quickly search for a keyword. I want to change the case of the last searched pattern in the easiest possible way.

One way to do this is to use `\U\1` in the substitution part and pressing `Ctrl-r` followed by `/` in the search part of the standard substitution command, like this:

```
:%s/\(<Ctrl-r>/\)/\U\1/g
```

However, this is too unwieldy.

Is there some fast way to do this? That is, I press `#` key and then 4-5 keystrokes later, I have changed the case of all the matches.

Comment: `:%s//\U\1/g` an empty pattern uses the last search pattern. I am pretty sure we have a duplicate question on here, but I can't find it.

Comment: @statox No. `:%s//\U\1/g` doesn't work. It simply deletes all the values matching the last searched pattern.

Comment: Instead of `\1`, use `&` (or `\0`, which is the same)

Comment: @LucHermitte : You nailed it!! This is certainly fast. Please post this as answer.

Comment: Well, statox had the solution, but he missed the unneeded group :)

Comment: Actually I had already tried the @statox 's solution before he replied. So, technically, the credit goes to you.

Comment: Yup I didn't test it because I focused on the part where you needed to reuse the last search pattern.

Comment: Also I found the [similar question](https://vi.stackexchange.com/q/3427/1841) but it doesn't involve the capture group so I guess that's not an exact duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two little things to change

1. First `:s` (and well as other search commands) will search the last searched pattern if we double the separator (usually `/`).
2. Then of course, there is no longer a group. So we cannot use `\1`. Fortunately, there is the *match everything* group: `\0`, or its shortcut: `&`

Hence:

```
:s//\U&/g
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `gUgn` to upper-case the next search match.  Then press `.` repeatedly to keep changing more matches.

Note: This will not work with `'ignorecase'` enabled (because the ignorecase setting will make `gn` select the current match over and over again). You can toggle the setting with `:set ic!` if needed (or add the `\C` atom to your pattern, which will make sure that the 'ignorecase' option does not apply).

Comment: Wow. That is one creative solution. However, `.` doesn't work here. Can you clarify?

Comment: Works for me, maybe your vim is too old?

Comment: Or `g~` to actually invert the case

Comment: What Vim version do you have?

Comment: @shivams I don't suppose you have `'ignorecase'` enabled? I inadvertently tried it without doing `:set noic` first and things appeared to be broken when I hit `.`.

Comment: @BLayer Yes. That solves it. Doing `set noic` and then the `.` works. Thanks.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt should this be considered a bug or expected because the match is still matching after the `gU` operation?

Comment: @Mass I am not sure I understand the problem. What I understand is, that setting `ignorecase` makes gn select the current word over and over again. Only when unsetting `ignorecase`, gn won't match the word that the current cursor is on and move on to the next match.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt yes, that's right.  From a usability perspective it would be a bit nicer if dot could work in this case.  {op}gn . is a fairly common idiom which has a big flaw when {op} doesn't change the text enough to disallow a match

Comment: @Mass true, but not sure what to do against it, the whole point of adding `gn` was to be able to select the current word, if it matches. In any case, it might help to explicitly add `\C` to the pattern so that the 'ignorecase' setting does not apply.

Comment: @Mass I use `'ic'` 99% of the time and my reaction when I realized what was going on was more "Oh, yeah, I need to turn that off" than "Well that seems broken to me." .. FWIW!

Comment: Good tip, BTW. I wouldn't have thought of it. +1